# navigationdrawer and searchview functionality mixed

Tags: java, android

iam having a strange issue my navigation drawer and searchview functionality are mixed when i open my navigation drawer function onQueryChanged or onQuerySubmited are called even if i didn't click on the search icon !!

and another thing my navigation drawer when i click on it it opens the item in the gridview behind the place i click on it although i haven't handled the navigation drawer clicks yet it is something strange i think

[screenshot of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1uSf.jpg)

fragment contains the serachview and the navigation drawer

```
package besho.hallofmovies;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MovieFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

GridView myGridView ;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
ArrayList<MyMovies> myMovies = new ArrayList<MyMovies>();
MyDatabaseHandler adapter;
int myState=0;
boolean firstTime=true;
public FetchMovies fetchMovies;
MyCommunicator communicator;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    adapter = new MyDatabaseHandler(getActivity());

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        myState=savedInstanceState.getInt("myState", 0);
        firstTime=savedInstanceState.getBoolean("firstTime", true);
    }
    else myState=0;

    /*Log.d("myFilter",myState+"");
    Log.d("myFilter",firstTime +"");*/

    communicator = (MyCommunicator) getActivity();
}



@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (firstTime)
    {
        setStateAs();
        firstTime=false;
    }
    updateMovies(myState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

public void setStateAs ()
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putBoolean("case", true);
    edit.commit();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    myGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

public void updateMovies (int s)
{
    if (s == 5)showFav();

    else
    {
        fetchMovies = new FetchMovies();
        fetchMovies.buildURL(s);
        fetchMovies.execute();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.movie_fragment, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    searchView.setQueryHint("enter the movie/tv show name");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            Log.d("myFilter","submit");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            Log.d("myFilter","ch");
            return false;
        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("myState", myState);
    outState.putBoolean("firstTime", firstTime);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        //Log.d("myFilter","do code");

        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_mostPopular)
    {
        myState=1;
        updateMovies(myState);
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_mostRated)
    {
        myState=2;
        updateMovies(myState);
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_tv)
    {
        myState=3;
        updateMovies(myState);
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_movie)
    {
        myState=4;
        updateMovies(myState);
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_favourite)
    {
        myState=5;
        showFav();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void showFav ()
{
    if(adapter.getMovies().isEmpty())
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"sorry,you don`t have any favourite movies",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    else{
        myMovies = adapter.getMovies();
        MoviesAdapter myAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(getActivity());
        myGridView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie, container, false);
    myGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),loadData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(),drawerLayout,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
        {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView)
        {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //drawerToggle.syncState();
    return view ;
}

public static List<Row> loadData ()
{
    List<Row> list = new ArrayList<>();

    int[] imagesID = {R.drawable.movies,R.drawable.tv,R.drawable.favourite,R.drawable.top_rated,R.drawable.most_popular};
    String[] dataText = {"Movies","TV Shows","Favourites","Top Rated","Most Popular"};

    for (int i=0;i<imagesID.length && i<dataText.length;i++)
    {
        Row item = new Row();
        item.imageId=imagesID[i];
        item.text=dataText[i];

        list.add(item);

    }

    return list;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    SharedPreferences p = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myBool", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (p.getBoolean("singleFrag",true)) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MovieDetailActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("title", myMovies.get(position).original_title);  //5
        i.putExtra("poster", myMovies.get(position).poster_path);    //1
        i.putExtra("id", myMovies.get(position).item_id);            //2
        //Log.d("myFilter",""+myMovies.get(position).item_id);
        i.putExtra("date", myMovies.get(position).release_date);     //4
        i.putExtra("rate", myMovies.get(position).vote_average);     //6
        i.putExtra("overview", myMovies.get(position).overview);    //3
        i.putExtra("tvORmov", prefs.getBoolean("case", true));
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else
    {
        communicator.respond(myMovies.get(position));
    }

}


class FetchMovies extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList<MyMovies>> {


    int myCase = 1;
    final String baseUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/";
    final String movie = "movie/";
    final String tv    =    "tv/";
    final String apiKey  = "api_key=f06b4506f14971248b2838078370f394";
    final String popular= "popular?";
    final String top_Rated = "top_rated?";
    String urlAdress = baseUrl + movie +popular+ apiKey;

    String myJSON = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    FetchMovies ()
    {

    }

    public void buildURL (int s)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        if (s == 1)
        {
            if (prefs.getBoolean("case",true))
            {
                urlAdress = baseUrl + movie + popular + "&" + apiKey;
                myCase=1;
            }
            else
            {
                urlAdress = baseUrl + tv + popular + "&" + apiKey;
                myCase = 2;
            }
            //Log.d("myFilter",urlAdress+"    s=1");
        }
        if (s == 2)
        {
            if (prefs.getBoolean("case",true))
            {
                urlAdress = baseUrl + movie + top_Rated + "&" + apiKey;
                myCase=1;
            }
            else
            {
                urlAdress = baseUrl + tv + top_Rated + "&" + apiKey;
                myCase = 2;
            }
            //Log.d("myFilter",urlAdress+"    s=1");
        }
        if (s == 3)
        {
            urlAdress = baseUrl + tv + popular + "&" + apiKey;
            myCase = 2;
            edit.putBoolean("case", false);
            edit.commit();
            //Log.d("myFilter",urlAdress+"    s=3");
        }
        if (s == 4)
        {
            urlAdress = baseUrl + movie + popular + "&" + apiKey;
            myCase=1;
            edit.putBoolean("case", true);
            edit.commit();
           // Log.d("myFilter",urlAdress+"    s=4");
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<MyMovies> doInBackground(Void... params) {



        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlAdress);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myJSON = buffer.toString();
        try {
            return parseMyJson(myJSON);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Log.d("myFilter",myJSON);

        return null;
    }

    public ArrayList<MyMovies> parseMyJson (String json) throws JSONException
    {
        myMovies.clear();
        final String poster_path="poster_path";
        final String adult="adult";
        final String overview="overview";
        final String release_date="release_date";
        final String original_title="original_title";
        final String air_date="first_air_date";
        final String original_name="original_name";
        final String vote_count = "vote_count";
        final String video="video";
        final String vote_average="vote_average";
        final String item_id ="id";

        JSONObject allMovies = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray results = allMovies.getJSONArray("results");

        for (int i=0;i<results.length();i++)
        {

            boolean ad=false;
            boolean vid=false;
            String release="";
            String title="";

            JSONObject film = results.getJSONObject(i);
            String poster = film.getString(poster_path);
            String review = film.getString(overview);
            int votes = film.getInt(vote_count);
            int id = film.getInt(item_id);
            double voteAverage = film.getDouble(vote_average);

            if (myCase == 1) {
                ad = film.getBoolean(adult);
                release = film.getString(release_date);
                title = film.getString(original_title);
                vid = film.getBoolean(video);
            }
            if (myCase == 2)
            {
                release = film.getString(air_date);
                title = film.getString(original_name);
            }




            MyMovies temp = new MyMovies(poster,id,ad,review,release,title,votes,vid,voteAverage,false);
            //Log.d("myFilter",""+temp.adult);
            myMovies.add(temp);
        }
        return myMovies;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<MyMovies> s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        MoviesAdapter myAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(getActivity());
        myGridView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        //Log.d("myFilter",myMovies.get(0).poster_path);

    }


}

class MoviesAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    ArrayList<MyMovies> movies;
    Context context;

    MoviesAdapter (Context c)
    {

        this.context=c;
        movies = myMovies;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movies.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return movies.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    class ImageViewHolder
    {
        ImageView myImage;
        ImageViewHolder(View v)
        {
            myImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View item=convertView;
        ImageViewHolder myHolder;
        if (item == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false);
            myHolder = new ImageViewHolder(item);
            item.setTag(myHolder);
        }

        else
        {
            myHolder = (ImageViewHolder) item.getTag();
        }

        MyMovies temp = movies.get(position);

        Picasso.with(context).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + temp.poster_path).into(myHolder.myImage);
        return item;
    }
}}
```

the fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:columnWidth="180dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/selector"
    />

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:background="#EEE"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="left">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/movie_night"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

the menu.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_favourite"
    android:title="@string/favourite"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_tv"
    android:title="@string/tv"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_movie"
    android:title="@string/movie"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_mostPopular"
    android:title="@string/mostPopular_button"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_mostRated"
    android:title="@string/mostRated_button"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

the searchview configration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
```

the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="besho.hallofmovies">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MovieDetailActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>

</application>
```